# What should I test for user registration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Currently working on an MVC application, which has a registration form with some 12-14 fields that the user will have to fill in in order to register to our site. There are two requirements about the user input, and those are, surprisingly, that he provides a unique email and a unique username, ones that still don't exist in our database. I already have tests about those validations, and the rest of the user input correctness is left to validation notations in the model, like the date format and the password strength requirements and so on, like this:.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your password is required")]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 8 and 20                                                           characters")]
[RegularExpression(@"(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$", ErrorMessage = "Needs to have lowercase, uppercase and a number")]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Without testing these notations, I guess the only test I need to write about this logic are those about validating username and email uniqueness and adding a record to the db, which I already have, but I fear that only 3 tests might be too little. Although I think (and hope, honestly) that I don't need tests for the out-of-the-box notation validations, I would like to hear that from someone more experienced and less lazy :) Also, if you could point out some general rules about what else should be tested when a user is registering, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you someday decide to override the `RegularExpression` class you would know if your tests fail. Up to you to decide where to draw the line. I would say its a small effort.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't write unit tests just for the sake of writing them.  More often than not they end up not being useful and not really proving anything.

These are the things that I would generally write tests for.

- Business requirements. The business have asked for these so you better make damn sure they work.
- Normal flow/usage.  General tests that prove it behaves how you want it to.
- Edge cases.  They may not happen very often but cover it with a test.
- Bugs. Need to prove that bad boy is history.
- Bacon. Always test for Bacon.

Comment: Well I think I have 1, 2, and 3 covered. I still have no idea how a test for bugs is made though, since for now I can't think of what could possibly go wrong with my application. I know I'll pay one day for saying that...

Comment: What I mean by bugs is, whenever you find a bug and fix it, write a test to prove it's fixed.